# Get element style from directive - Randomly fails

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In an angular directive I want get some style (example: *backgroundImage*) to store it for future use. I have the follow code:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            terminal: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {                                 
                // examples of how get it
                console.log(element.css('background-image'));
                console.log(window.getComputedStyle(element[0]).backgroundImage);
            }
         };
     });
```

Most of the time I get the *backgroundImage* value successfully, but timetimes I get just *null* value. Then I refresh page and get the value successfully again. How can I do to get style properties from directive without have this problem?

Any tip or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure the css is being read once all content has been loaded by waiting for the `$viewContentLoaded` event:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            terminal: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {                                 
                scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
                    console.log(element.css('background-image'));
                    console.log(window.getComputedStyle(element[0]).backgroundImage);
                });
            }
         };
     });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the event $viewContentLoaded never gets triggered.